# How to access the last element of a bash associative array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, element, associative-array

I am trying to access the last element of a bash associative array using the below code:
# Declare an associative array
declare -A myAssocArray

```
# Add key-value pairs to the associative array
myAssocArray["name"]="John"
myAssocArray["age"]=30
myAssocArray["city"]="New York"
myAssocArray["country"]="USA"

keys=("${!myAssocArray[@]}")  # Get all keys
last_key="${keys[-1]}"        # Access the last key
last_element="${myAssocArray[$last_key]}"  # Access the last elemen
echo "$last_element"
```

it outputs: john instead of USA
actually I am trying to seek if any method is available like negative indices for last element access in assoc. arrays

Comment: The keys in an associative array are not ordered.  There is no concept of "first" and "last".  They are delivered in essentially random order.

Comment: So don't use associative array, but simple array with numeric keys

Comment: Thank you all for assistance. I understand the issue now

Comment: in some situations, you could maintain a helper indexed array - whenever you insert a hash key for the first time, append the key as a value in the helper. Then you can access the "last" element of the hash (the one most recently added) by dereferencing through the helper. eg: `${hash["${helper[-1]}"]}`